# Variable is nil after assigning value in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, async-await, viewwillappear

I am new in the async/await in swift and I am trying to assign the `job` global variable in MyViewController a value using an async function which is then called in the ViewWillAppear.
Inside the async function, I get a value for `job` but when I try to pass that to a cell property in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` I get `nil`.
Can anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
  private var job: Job!

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    Task { [weak self] in
      await self?.getJob()
    }
  }
  

   private func getJob() async {
    job = await viewModel.getJob(byID: "xxxxxxx") // will return a Job Object
    // more code...
    print(job) // it's ok 
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    
    print(job) // it is nil!!!
  }
}
```

Comment: You need `tableView.reloadData()` after `job = ....`

Comment: Could you instead of just `print(job)`, do `print("job inside getJob(): \(job))` & `print("job inside cellForRowAt: \(job))`? And see the order of the prints? You might want to reload the tableView when you finally got `job`.

Comment: @Larme I tried it and ```print("job inside cellForRowAt: \(job)")``` is printed first with value ```nil``` then the ```print("job inside getJob(): \(job)")``` gives back the ```job``` object. Now I see why it is happening but how can I fix this where should I put ```tableView.reloadData()```?

Comment: When yourr VC appears, its UITableView appears too. By default, its checks its data source, and try to load the cells. If you put 1 in numberOfRow, it will try to show one row, and will call cellForRowAt. Then, after some point, your `getJob()` manage to retrieve the `job`. So, call `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.yourTableView.reloadData() }` Until `job` is get, return that you have no rows (or use an "intermediary view to show that it's loading)...

Comment: @Larme you mean to use ```DispatchQueue.main.async { self.yourTableView.reloadData() }``` in the ```private func getJob() async {``` I am not sure?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, tableView loads before job data fetch. So you should add tableView.reloadData() after fetch the job data to reload the tableView with new fetched data.

```
private func getJob() async {
    job = await viewModel.getJob(byID: "xxxxxxx") // will return a Job Object
    // more code...
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think that is what the other guys were suggesting also but by adding ```DispatchQueue.main.async { self.yourTableView.reloadData() }``` is more like a "hack" I think because you get a ```nil``` first then reload the whole tableview to get a value for the ```job``` and I don't want to reload the whole tableview since I have different sections with different cell sizes in there. Is there a "better" way to archive this?

Comment: At the beginning, your job variable has no data. After `getJob()` fetch the data, you have all the data you need. when the state changes from `nil` to some data, it is suitable to use `reloadData()`. But if you have another scenario like insertion and deletion or pagination, that's another story. If you have these kind of cases, please let us know.

Comment: Yes, I will add insertion to that tableview and also pagination and that is my main problem for adding ```tableView.reloadData()``` I think it will cause some problems in the long run.

Comment: Usually, `reloadData()` is also used for pagination. But there is an option for making updates on tableView by manual. You can insert new sections and rows according to fetched new data. But this operation will require more calculation for exact insertion count to be handle. But it is possible.